# How do I plot multiple normal regressions in R on the same chart?

Tags: r

I need to plot multiple distributions on the same chart, my data is as follows:

```
     mean    sd 
DIV  0.1790  0.2099 
CAS  0.1040  0.1576 
ATL  0.0960  0.2218 
COM  0.0980  0.1768
```

Comment: is something like this you are after? http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_linerange.html

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, this should do it. The title of your post says 'normal regression' though, no idea what that is.

```
normalpars <- read.table(text=
"code mean sd 
DIV 0.1790 0.2099 
CAS 0.1040 0.1576 
ATL 0.0960 0.2218 
COM 0.0980 0.1768", header=TRUE)

plot(1, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(0,3), type='n',
     xlab="X", ylab="Density")
for(i in 1:nrow(normalpars)){
  curve(dnorm(x, mean=normalpars$mean[i], sd=normalpars$sd[i]),
    add=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful, apologize for the typo at the top.

Comment: One more question, can you show me how to add color (and a legend) the respective distributions?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing using ggplot: (calling your table `df`)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
# using density functions [dnorm(...)]
x <- seq(-1,1,by=0.01)
dist <- apply(df,1,function(z){dnorm(x,mean=z[1],sd=z[2])})
dist <- data.frame(x=x, dist)
gg   <- melt(dist,id.vars="x")
ggplot(gg) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=value, color=variable))
```

[image]